# jQuery, editing inline style tag

Tags: jquery, tags, styles

I'm having a problem with some css+javascript. You see, I'm trying to make some sort of a wysiwyg webpage style editor in which there is an iframe which load a webpage containing code of something like this.

```
<head>
<style id=mystyle>
  /* something is here */
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Other, quite a lot autogenerated stuff along with javascript that add some interactivity.</h1>
</body>
```

Now, I need to modify the content of #mystyle so that it reflect to the page in realtime. Using jquery, I tried to do so using several technique, like:

1. `$(#mystyle).html(newcss);`
2. `$(#mystyle).replaceWith("<style id='mystyle'>"+newcss+"</style>")`
3. `$(#mystyle).after("the newcss along with style tag")`, then delete the old one.
4. `$(#mystyle).delete()` //just to see what happen.

All of the above fail to change the look of the webpage. In fact, deleting the tag (4.), did not turn the page ugly and I did check using "Inspect Element", the html does change but the appearance do not. So.... what did I do wrong?

Comment: how about helping us out with a sample on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `html` seems to work just fine. see:

http://jsfiddle.net/tGSkS/

Comment: It turns out it does work, but the css precedence is somewhat wrong, thats why I cannot figure out why it cannot preview it but instead when reload with the new css it looked fine. Sorry for bugging around.

Comment: update: Actually the precedence is also correct. The problem is there is another link tag in the webpage which load the old css, causing all this mess. I feel terribly sorry for this. such small mistake hours lost.

Answer (score 0):

if there are specific elements that you want to style on page load, you can do the following

```
$(function(){

  $('element-selector').css({
     style1:'value',
     style2:'value',
     style2:'value',
   });  

});
```

or on the server, conditionally render or dynamically build your style sheet.